# What does this 'fancy' mean?

Tags: vocabulary

> If anyone looked out of their window now, even beady-eyed Mrs.
>   Dursley, they wouldn’t be able to see anything that was happening down
>   on the pavement. Dumbledore slipped the Put-Outer back inside his
>   cloak and set off down the street toward number four, where he sat
>   down on the wall next to the cat. He didn’t look at it, but after a
>   moment he spoke to it.
>    “***Fancy*** seeing you here,
>   Professor McGonagall.”
>    He turned to smile at the
>   tabby, but it had gone. Instead he was smiling at a rather
>   severe-looking woman who was wearing square glasses exactly the shape
>   of the markings the cat had had around its eyes. She, too, was wearing
>   a cloak, an emerald one. Her black hair was drawn into a tight bun.
>   She looked distinctly ruffled.  (Harry Potter and the Sorcerer's
>   Stone)

What does the word ‘fancy’ mean, used when meeting someone you know on a place you’ve not expected? I don’t find any right meaning in [OALD](http://oald8.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/dictionary/fancy) or [Merriam-Webster’s](http://www.learnersdictionary.com/definition/fancy).

Comment: http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/fancy
Definition #2, synonym of *imagine*. "*Imagine seeing you here, ..."

Comment: Also definition 5 on the [OALD page you linked](http://oald8.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/dictionary/fancy).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As commented by @Walter, in OP's context, *fancy* is a synonym of *imagine, believe.* But the usage is [becoming increasingly "dated"...](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=fancy%20that&year_start=1850&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=)

[image]

Many of the above instances will be the idiomatic exclamation [*"Well, fancy that"!*](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22fancy%20that%20he%20exclaimed%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#fp=a95bff877a5c63f8&q=%22fancy%20that%20he%20said%22&tbm=bks) (equivalent to *"Imagine that!"*, *"What a surprise!"*, *"How strange!"*, etc.). In OP's context, Dumbledore could quite naturally have used any of those (possibly preceded or followed by something like *"I didn't expect to see you here!"*).

---

Note that Dumbledore is an elderly British schoolmaster in a relatively "formal" situation (he's greeting Professor McGonagall, one of his staff who apparently happens to have adopted the form of a cat).

Idiomatic expressions as used by Dumbledore won't necessarily be so natural for younger speakers, and per @StoneyB's comment below, even Dumbledore is speaking [ironically](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/irony) here. Brits in particular still use *fancy = like, want, be attracted to* quite naturally today, but *fancy = imagine, believe, think* is now largely confined to ironic/sarcastic contexts.

Comment: +1 I think it's also pretty clear that Dumbledore's 'surprise' is ironic - but that of course is LitCrit.

Comment: @StoneyB: I think you're absolutely right that Dumbledore's 'surprise' is ironic, which I agree *technically speaking* is an OT LitCrit issue. But your comment reminds me that I had intended to make one more observation regarding current usage of this and related expressions, before I was pulled away from the keyboard. Edit follows...

Comment: Note that *fancy* is generally old fashioned even in the UK, with the one key exception of (esp. northern) young Brits who still using the word *fancy* to mean *sexually attracted to* (e.g. "Whadda ya talkin' bout? Laura *well* fancies you, mate")

Comment: @Matt: Perhaps I didn't express myself well, but that was pretty much the point I was trying to make in my edit just now. I think you're probably right that non-facetious *fancy = be [sexually] attracted to* is more common in the Midlands and North. But I have the impression *"I don't fancy that!"* (*"That does **not** appeal to me!"*, indicating mild to moderate revulsion for some proffered food, etc.) is still alive and kicking throughout the land.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: That's true. Thinking about it, "I'm parched! Fancy a quick beer down the local?" would be perfectly normal and idiomatic in British English.

Comment: Worth mentioning that this use of "fancy" is related to the word "fanciful" and expression "flight of fancy," both referring to imagination or whimsy.